# Get all row values ​in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function to add rows to my table

```
var div = $('#tabela-fornecedorPreco');
            var newRow = '<tr>' +
                '<td><input type="hidden" id="fornecedor_material" name="fornecedor_material[]" value="' + idMaterial + '">' + nomeMaterial + '</td>' +
                '<td><input type="hidden" id="fornecedor_id" name="fornecedor_id[]" value="' + fornecedorVal + '">' + fornecedor + '</td>' +
                '<td><input type="hidden" id="fornecedor_preco_unitario" name="fornecedor_preco_unitario[]" value="' + precoUnitarioCalculado + '">' + precoUnitarioCalculado + '</td>' +
                '<td><input type="hidden" id="fornecedor_preco_total" name="fornecedor_preco_total[]" value="' + precoTotalCalculado + '">' + precoTotalCalculado + '</td>' +
                '<td class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="label label-primary remover-telefone" onclick="removerLinha(this);" title="Excluir"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></td>' +
                '</tr>';
            div.find('#lista-fornecedorPreco').append(newRow);
```

I am trying to get all the data in this table with one function, to transfer the other, to another page using the following function:

```
function TransfereDados() {
var tabelaModal = $('#tabela-fornecedorPreco');
for (var i = 0, row; row = tabelaModal.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        var idMaterial = $("#fornecedorPrecoMaterialId").val();
        var qtdMaterial = $("#fornecedorPrecoMaterialQtd").val();
        var idFornecedor = $("#fornecedor_id").val();
        var idFornecedor = $("#fornecedor_preco_unitario").val();
        var idFornecedor = $("#fornecedor_preco_total").val();
        var div = $('#tabela-materiais-oculto');
        var newRow = '<tr style="display:none;">' +
            '<td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" id="fornecedor_material" name="fornecedor_material[]" value="' + idMaterial + '"></td>' +
            '<td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" id="qtd_material" name="qtd_material[]" value="' + qtdMaterial + '"></td>' +
            '<td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" id="fornecedor_id" name="fornecedor_id[]" value="' + idFornecedor + '"></td>' +
            '<td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" id="fornecedor_preco_unitario" name="fornecedor_preco_unitario[]" value="' + precoUnitario + '"></td>' +
            '<td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" id="fornecedor_preco_total" name="fornecedor_preco_total[]" value="' + precoTotal + '"></td>' +
            '</tr>';
        div.find('#lista-materiais-oculto').append(newRow);
    }
}
```

}

I would like the TransfereDados () function loop to go through all my first table and get all the values ​​so that I can put it in the second table.

Comment: How do you mean 'take all the data from it'? As in, take the HTML from it? If so select the `tr` elements and use `append()` or `appendTo()`. If that's not what you meant please edit the question to give a clearer explanation of your goal, and an example of the code you've written to achieve it so that we can help you debug it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same `ids` for mutliple inputs so first change them to `class` . Then , use `.each` loop to iterate through your table trs and then using `.find("classname")`  get input values from first table and assign them to second table .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
TransfereDados();

function TransfereDados() {
  //loop through trs 
  $('#lista-fornecedorPreco tr').each(function() {
    var selector = $(this);
    //get required input value using `.find`
    var idMaterial = selector.find(".fornecedor_material").val();
    var qtdMaterial = selector.find(".fornecedor_id").val(); //i am not sure what is this..
    var idFornecedor = selector.find(".fornecedor_id").val();
    var precoUnitario = selector.find(".fornecedor_preco_unitario").val();
    var precoTotal = selector.find(".fornecedor_preco_total").val();
    console.log("idMaterial -> " + idMaterial + " precoUnitario-> " + precoUnitario + " precoTotal -> " + precoTotal)
    var div = $('#tabela-materiais-oculto');
    //change `id` to `class` (add disply:none type="hidden" at your end..) i have remove them just for demo..
    var newRow = '<tr style="">' +
      '<td style=""><input type="text" class="fornecedor_material" name="fornecedor_material[]" value="' + idMaterial + '"></td>' +
      '<td style=""><input type="text" class="qtd_material" name="qtd_material[]" value="' + qtdMaterial + '"></td>' +
      '<td style=""><input type="text" class="fornecedor_id" name="fornecedor_id[]" value="' + idFornecedor + '"></td>' +
      '<td style=""><input type="text" class="fornecedor_preco_unitario" name="fornecedor_preco_unitario[]" value="' + precoUnitario + '"></td>' +
      '<td style=""><input type="text" class="fornecedor_preco_total" name="fornecedor_preco_total[]" value="' + precoTotal + '"></td>' +
      '</tr>';
    div.find('#lista-materiais-oculto').append(newRow);
  })

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabela-fornecedorPreco" class="table">
  <tbody id="lista-fornecedorPreco">
    <tr>
      <!--change ids to class-->
      <td><input type="hidden" class="fornecedor_material" name="fornecedor_material[]" value="1">Abc1</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" class="fornecedor_id" name="fornecedor_id[]" value="1">A1</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" class="fornecedor_preco_unitario" name="fornecedor_preco_unitario[]" value="3">3
        <td>
          <td><input type="hidden" class="fornecedor_preco_total" name="fornecedor_preco_total[]" value="3">3</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="label label-primary remover-telefone" onclick="removerLinha(this);" title="Excluir"><i class="fas fa-times">x</i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" class="fornecedor_material" name="fornecedor_material[]" value="2">Abc2</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" class="fornecedor_id" name="fornecedor_id[]" value="2">A2</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" class="fornecedor_preco_unitario" name="fornecedor_preco_unitario[]" value="14">14
        <td>
          <td><input type="hidden" class="fornecedor_preco_total" name="fornecedor_preco_total[]" value="12">12</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="label label-primary remover-telefone" onclick="removerLinha(this);" title="Excluir"><i class="fas fa-times">x</i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
Table 2:
<table id="tabela-materiais-oculto" class="table">
  <tbody id="lista-materiais-oculto">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly for me, and it is much simpler than I thought it would be. Thank you very much for the time you spent writing the answer, simple and objective, thankful! =)

Comment: Your welcome :) .glad i was able to helped.